# Why pip cannot install package even having permissions for both user & system repository?

Tags: python, linux, pip

When I upgrade my user's pip repository with the following command:

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U
```

I got the following error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 330, in clobber
    os.utime(destfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.pyc'
```

However the file that triggers this error already has all permissions opened:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.pyc -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 315 Jul  5 20:47 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.pyc
```

Why pip is still unable to work on it? What has to be done to fix it?

Comment: Did you try sudo pip freeze ?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to have 777 permissions on any file. Also, since you have `pip` in `~/.local`, try using the `--user` option to the last `pip` command.

Comment: Looks like --user option triggers another dependency error:     error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yOg0AX/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-51tcto-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yOg0AX/lxml/

Comment: Looks like your setuptools are broken, so you might need to reinstall it

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this error when running `pip install` by a different user than owner of python files. It's a strange (and ugly) limitation of Linux: any user with write permission can set file times to current time (touch), but only owner of file can set arbitrary times. pip/wheel is trying to set exact times, and kernel doesn't allow it.

Relevant pip issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2125

Beta (than nuthin) solution is to change file owner or run pip as file owner user.

I am desperately looking for a better solution, please help in comments.